# How to insert a new xml node to an empty parent node?

Tags: xml, powershell

Here is my xml file structure: bookshelf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <bookshelf>
  </bookshelf>
</Root>
```

I simply want to insert a new XML node to the empty bookshelf node, here is my powershell script

```
$xmlPath = ".\bookshelf.xml"
[xml]$myXml = Get-Content -Path $xmlPath -Raw
$bookshelf =  $myXml.Root.bookshelf

$bookNode = $myXml.CreateElement("Book");
$bookNode.InnerText = "Book1";
$bookshelf.PrependChild($bookNode);
$myXml.Save($xmlPath)
```

I get the following exception in run-time

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'PrependChild'.
At powershell.ps1:7 char:1
+ $bookshelf.PrependChild($bookNode);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I try to debug and check the selected xml node is empty and powershell doesn't consider it is a xml node and exception thrown. After I added extra node in the empty node then it works:

```
  <bookshelf>
    <test> testdata <test>
  </bookshelf>
```

But it is not the case I prefer, it should be able to insert a new node to empty tag. Does anyone experience this issue before?

Comment: What if you try `$bookshelf =  $myXml.SelectSingleNode("//Root/bookshelf")` and then run your code? It is also possible you will have issues with your `.Save()` command unless you are in the `[environment]::currentdirectory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell has some helper functionality for xml documents - your `$bookshelf =  $myXml.Root.bookshelf` is returning the *InnerText* of the `bookshelf` element, not the element itself.

If you do this instead it will return the element...

```bsh
$bookshelf = $myXml.SelectSingleNode("/Root/bookshelf")
```

and then the rest of your example creates an xml document as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <bookshelf>
    <Book>Book1</Book>
  </bookshelf>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I didn’t think of it returns element instead of inner text.